# How to access a global var in Kivy file?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have a global variable called Tiles and want to set the number of cols in the TreasureHuntGrid class to the kivy file.

Main.py

```
Tiles = 5
class TreasureHuntGrid(GridLayout):
    global Tiles
```

.kv

```
<TreasureHuntGrid>:
cols: #Don't know what should I put in here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Globals are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). If you want to have a variable accessible from any widget it's better to put it into the `Application` class, since you will only have one instance in your program:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    cols: app.tiles
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
""")

class MyWidget(GridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    tiles = 5
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Having said that, you can access global variables like this if you really need that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

tiles = 5

Builder.load_string("""
#: import tiles __main__.tiles

<MyWidget>:
    cols: tiles
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
    Label:
        text: "test"
""")

class MyWidget(GridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```